# Passing variables from JavaScript to PHP code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass 2 variables from PHP to JavaScript and the vice versa.

I understand how to pass one variable, and it's okay, but when I tried to pass 2 variales, one of them passed, the other one didn't work.

Here is the code:

(1) file1.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var id = <?php echo $id ; ?>
var q= <?php echo $q ; ?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost/site/js/java.js">      </script>
```

(2) Java.js:

```
http://localhost/site/file2.php?id="+id +"&q="+q
```

(3) file2.php:

```
 $id = $_GET['id']; >> it works fine
 $q= $_GET['q']; >> doesn't pass (error: undefined)
```

I am not sure where the problem is, I just think it's in the number (2) step.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Java.js` did you just...

Comment: have you verified that `var q=` is set and is not null. have you looked at `http://localhost/site/file2.php?id="+id +"&q="+q` after it was parsed to make sure that the `q` value is not empty?

Comment: Check if q is undefined if so you pass `&q=undefined` and you will have undefined in php.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I am sure q is not null, I just couldn't show its value here, if you tried to edit this question you will see full code.

Comment: the second variable is failing, meaning it is likely a case of a malformed get statement... does the get statement look normal try alerting it instead of importing it.

Comment: my guess is q is a string!

Comment: I use q for search (q=search key words), but I have the same problem when I try to pass other variables like country, category... etc

Comment: @JoshuaByer You are right, thank you. Also, thanks to jcubic again for his comment, the problem is in variable GET

Comment: @TobyAllen your guess is true, it's a string. when I tried to set the q to a number, it worked well. I couldn't solve the problem till now, do you have a solution?

Comment: var q= "<?php echo $q ; ?>"

Comment: @TobyAllen I already do this. I am sure now the problem is here (2) Java.js: http://localhost/site/file2.php?id="+id +"&q="+q because when I viewed the page source of the first php file I saw the value printed inside the script. If you have another solution please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, if q is a string then it needs to be enclosed in quotes. Remember all you php code is doing is generating text.

```
var q= <?php echo $q ; ?>
```

Should be

```
var q= "<?php echo $q ; ?>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, finely it worked, the 'magic' quotes solved the problem :)